# Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr

Tags: python, redirect, stdout, stderr

Is it possible to temporarily redirect stdout/stderr in Python (i.e. for the duration of a method)?

#### Edit:

The problem with the current solutions (which I at first remembered but then forgot) is that they don't *redirect*; rather, they just replace the streams in their entirety. Hence, if a method has a ***local* copy** of one the variable for any reason (e.g. because the stream was passed as a parameter to something), it won't work.

Any solutions?

Comment: Redirecting stdout/stderr isn't uncommon (or, at least, not unheard of) — the answers here explain the process nicely.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: while you should never write library code that has outputs to `stderr` or `stdout` wired-in, you can't always avoid *using* that kind of code.

Comment: @Mehrdad Try replacing sys.__stdout__ first thing in your code, _before_ you import the third-party modules

Comment: @Rob: I think you missed the 2nd word in my title. :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad Nope. Replace sys.__stdout__ early in your code with your own stream-like object (i.e. implements `.write()`). All references to sys.stdout point to it. Have it proxy to a changeable stream, defaulting to stdout. You should then have the ability to switch the proxied stream at will. I haven't tried this; I'm thinking out loud.

Comment: @Rob: Oh I see... it's an good idea (though overkill!); I might try it. :)

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but for reference, you don't need to store the values of `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`. There is `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__`. [(reference)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To solve the issue that some function might have cached `sys.stdout` stream as a local variable and therefore replacing the global `sys.stdout` won't work inside that function, you could redirect at a file descriptor level (`sys.stdout.fileno()`) e.g.:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

def some_function_with_cached_sys_stdout(stdout=sys.stdout):
    print('cached stdout', file=stdout)

with stdout_redirected(to=os.devnull), merged_stderr_stdout():
    print('stdout goes to devnull')
    some_function_with_cached_sys_stdout()
    print('stderr also goes to stdout that goes to devnull', file=sys.stderr)
print('stdout is back')
some_function_with_cached_sys_stdout()
print('stderr is back', file=sys.stderr)
```

[`stdout_redirected()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) redirects all output for `sys.stdout.fileno()` to a given filename,  file object, or file descriptor (`os.devnull` in the example).

[`stdout_redirected()` and `merged_stderr_stdout()` are defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279).

Answer (score 98):

You can also put the redirection logic in a contextmanager.

```
import os
import sys

class RedirectStdStreams(object):
    def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None):
        self._stdout = stdout or sys.stdout
        self._stderr = stderr or sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stdout, self.old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
        self.old_stdout.flush(); self.old_stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = self._stdout, self._stderr

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._stdout.flush(); self._stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr

if __name__ == '__main__':

    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    print('Fubar')

    with RedirectStdStreams(stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull):
        print("You'll never see me")

    print("I'm back!")
```

Comment: This answer replaces `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` instead of redirecting them as OP asked in the edited version of the question. See [my answer that does redirect them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434728/4279).

Comment: @RobCowie: Style question: Is there a reason why you make `self._stdout` "protected" (in the Python sense), vs `self.__stdout` "private" (in the Python sense)?

Comment: I don't seem to ever create private double-underscore properties. I've yet to find a situation that warrants it.

Comment: @kevinarpe - there's no difference between `x._bar` and `x.__bar` except that `x.__bar` is harder to get at, debugging wise due to name-mangling. It doesn't *actually* make the variable private, so it doesn't buy you anything, but makes your debugging life more difficult. In general, stick with a single underscore unless you're dealing with multiple inheritance and have a particular reason to want dunderscore (both classes' variables need to exist? I feel like there are more elegant solutions)

Comment: perhaps that `with` is better as  `with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull, RedirectStdStreams(stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull):` so that devnull is also closed fine

Answer (score 38):

starting from python 3.4 there is the context manager [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=context#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        # do stuff...
```

to completely silence `stdout` this works:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with redirect_stdout(None):
    # do stuff...
```

Comment: I just tried this with `redirect_stdout(None)` and it didn't work. The module producing the output is written in C++, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: how 'does it not work'? because it really should! see e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757674/why-does-sys-stdout-none-work

Comment: Maybe it's just a corner case, I tried wrapping a call to `caffe.Net()` in `with redirect_stderr(None)` and still got a load of debug messaged dumped to stderr. Turns out you can disable those for the specific case of Caffe another way but I guess disabling standard output is not that easy for modules that use `std::iostream` under the hood.

Comment: what if one wants to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same place?

Comment: @baxx `with redirect_stdout(sys.stderr):` and then you could redirect `stderr` (or the other way round).

Comment: If you're dealing with code that writes to `sys.stdout` directly you'll need to redirect it to `/dev/null`, rather than setting it to `None`, like so: `with redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, "w"))`

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure what temporary redirection means. But, you  can reassign streams like this and reset it back.

```
temp = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = temp
```

Also to write to sys.stderr within print stmts like this.

```
 print >> sys.stderr, "Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:"
```

Regular print will to stdout.

Comment: I guess I could wrap a `try-finally` around that; seems like it'd work, though not as pretty as I wanted. Thanks +1

Comment: This example works for those of us stuck on python 2.2. Thanks

Comment: you don't need temp.  sys.__stderr__ stays as the correct object.

Comment: +1 for the cleanest and simplest solution I've seen to this problem

Comment: In Python you don't need the `temp` variable. You can call `sys.stdout, sys.stderr = sys.stderr, sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible with a decorator such as the following:

```
import sys

def redirect_stderr_stdout(stderr=sys.stderr, stdout=sys.stdout):
    def wrap(f):
        def newf(*args, **kwargs):
            old_stderr, old_stdout = sys.stderr, sys.stdout
            sys.stderr = stderr
            sys.stdout = stdout
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                sys.stderr, sys.stdout = old_stderr, old_stdout

        return newf
    return wrap
```

Use as:

```
@redirect_stderr_stdout(some_logging_stream, the_console):
def fun(...):
    # whatever
```

or, if you don't want to modify the source for `fun`, call it directly as

```
redirect_stderr_stdout(some_logging_stream, the_console)(fun)
```

But note that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: +1 seems to be what I need. Just curious, why'd you do an `except: raise`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: forget about the `except: raise` thing, it was a thinko on my part. I rewrote the whole thing btw.; I always get the level of nesting in decorators wrong the first time, but it actually works now.

Comment: You know, I noticed a problem: What if a program has *cached* the stream objects (e.g. passed them as a parameter to a function that accepts a stream)? Then this wouldn't work. :\ Is there a way to redirect the streams themselves, rather than replacing them with new streams?

Comment: @Mehrdad: then you'd do some low-level file descriptor magic, or even fork the process and redirect the streams in the child before performing the desired code, returning the result across a pipe. There's no silver bullet here, I'm afraid.

Comment: changereturn wrap(f) to return wrap

Answer (score 4):

Here's a context manager that I found useful. The nice things about this are that you can use it with the `with` statement and it also handles redirecting for child processes.

```python
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdchannel_redirected(stdchannel, dest_filename):
    """
    A context manager to temporarily redirect stdout or stderr

    e.g.:

    with stdchannel_redirected(sys.stderr, os.devnull):
        ...
    """

    try:
        oldstdchannel = os.dup(stdchannel.fileno())
        dest_file = open(dest_filename, 'w')
        os.dup2(dest_file.fileno(), stdchannel.fileno())

        yield
    finally:
        if oldstdchannel is not None:
            os.dup2(oldstdchannel, stdchannel.fileno())
        if dest_file is not None:
            dest_file.close()
```

The context for why I created this is at [this blog post](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2013/07/19/python-context-manager-for-redirected-stdout-and-stderr/).

Comment: Is it possible to no redirect the stdout to a file rather to just ignore it ?

Answer (score 2):

[Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) shows us a better way[1]:

```
import sys
with open(filepath + filename, "w") as f: #replace filepath & filename
    with f as sys.stdout:
        print("print this to file")   #will be written to filename & -path
```

After the with block the sys.stdout will be reset

[1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&list=PLQZM27HgcgT-6D0w6arhnGdSHDcSmQ8r3

Comment: -1 -- The `with` will **not** restore the initial `sys.stdout`. If you try to print something after those `with` blocks you receive a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`. You should remove the second `with` and put a `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` at the end of the first `with` block.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [contextlib.redirect_stdout(new_target)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) and [contextlib.redirect_stderr(new_target)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr). `redirect_stderr` is new in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use the `PHP` syntax of [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) functions in python3, and redirect the input into a file.

The outputs are being stored in a file, any type of stream could be used as well.

```
from functools import partial
output_buffer = None
print_orig = print
def ob_start(fname="print.txt"):
    global print
    global output_buffer
    print = partial(print_orig, file=output_buffer)
    output_buffer = open(fname, 'w')
def ob_end():
    global output_buffer
    close(output_buffer)
    print = print_orig
def ob_get_contents(fname="print.txt"):
    return open(fname, 'r').read()
```

Usage:

```
print ("Hi John")
ob_start()
print ("Hi John")
ob_end()
print (ob_get_contents().replace("Hi", "Bye"))
```

Would print

> Hi John
>   Bye John