# how to log background python script's output if some exception is not catched

Tags: python, logging

I have a python script running in background, and I want to log all the exception and output to a log file.

I know to use logging module and `try.. catch..` to log exception, but what if I missed some, is there any way to log these exceptions too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual technique is to use a try/except *Exception* at the highest level call (the main function).   This pretty much assures that you will not have "missed some".  *Exception* matches non-exiting exceptions, so it is casting a broad net.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to file handles.  They'll be available after your python exits if an uncaught exception is encountered.  Something like this:

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('myOut.txt', 'w')
sys.stderr = open('myErr.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: this will not add time on an exception quit, is it? I'm wondering if any way would work as the logging module's behavior.

Comment: @lxyu - I ... am not sure what you are asking.  This will redirect all of stdout or stderr to files, useful for when you'll be running a script in the background or in some way unattended and want a record of what it outputs.  The `logging` module supports the `write(str)` method, which means you could assign an instance of a log to either or both of these.