# Ignore stderr output for test result

Tags: python, jenkins, jython, nose

I am trying to test a package with `nose`. During one of the tests I write to `stderr`, this causes the test to be reported as broken in `Jenkins` (I start the test using `nose` and generate the Junit `.xml` output to determine the success)
Is it possible to ingore `stderr` or check it for certain values?

So fare my test looks roughly like this:

```
def testFunc() {
    f1()
    f2() }
```

And fails since I write to stderr from within, can I tell nose to ignore this or is the test missing something ( I expect it to fail only if an exception is generated)

**edit**:
The assumption that the error output caused the failure was wrong. Between the 100s of lines of debbuging output was an exception. (for some reason jenkins showed the unformated(no line feeds) output first, then the exception trace, and after that the output was once more, with linefeeds. I just overlooked the exception)

Comment: Have you tried to redirect the stderr? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to see the stderr, you could use `logging` [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).

Example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
# instead of sys.stderr.write():
logging.warning("This is a warning!")
```

In this instance, the warning is below the logging level threshold so it will not be printed to stderr. If you wanted to see the error but it doesn't have to be in real time, you could specify a log file (with the filename parameter to logging.basicConfig).