# Python stats: how do I write it to a (human readable) file

Tags: python, file-io, profiling

I am using Python's hotshot profiler: http://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html

It shows how to print the stats:

```
stats.print_stats(20)
```

But how do I get that into a file? I'm not sure how to get at the information so I can write it to a file using write().

EDIT:

I'd like the same easily readable result as is printed when it's done this way:

```
stats = hotshot.stats.load("stones.prof")
stats.strip_dirs()
stats.sort_stats('time', 'calls')
stats.print_stats(20)
```

So it looks like this:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    3.295    3.295   10.090   10.090 pystone.py:79(Proc0)
```

(So not for it to look like when I open stones.prof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the print_stats() function, starting with copying it from pstats.py. It returns a string, which can then be written to a file.  I have not tested every if-else loop, just that it works in the examples that I needed it for. I left the original lines commented out. I've left the variable names the same although it isn't really "self" that the function is using anymore.

```
stats = hotshot.stats.load("stones.prof")
stats.strip_dirs()
stats.sort_stats('time', 'calls')
readable_str = xprint_stats(stats, 20)

import pstats
def xprint_stats(self, *amount):
    x = ""
    for filename in self.files:
        x += " " + filename
    #if self.files: print >> self.stream
    # ?
    indent = ' ' * 8
    for func in self.top_level:
        #print >> self.stream, indent, xfunc_get_function_name(func)
        x += indent + pstats.func_get_function_name(func)

    #print >> self.stream, indent, self.total_calls, "function calls",
    x +=  indent + str(self.total_calls) + " function calls" + " "
    if self.total_calls != self.prim_calls:
        #print >> self.stream, "(%d primitive calls)" % self.prim_calls,
        x += "(%d primitive calls)" % self.prim_calls + " "
    #print >> self.stream, "in %.3f seconds" % self.total_tt
    #print >> self.stream
    x +=  "in %.3f seconds" % self.total_tt + "\n"
    #width, list = stats.get_print_list(amount)
    msg, width, list = xget_print_list(stats, amount)
    x += msg

    if list:
        #self.print_title()
        x += "\n" + '   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)'
        x += "\n"
        for func in list:
            #self.print_line(func)
            x +=  xprint_line(self, func) + "\n"
#        print >> self.stream
#        print >> self.stream
    #return self
    return x

def xprint_line(self, func):  
    x = ""
    cc, nc, tt, ct, callers = self.stats[func]
    c = str(nc)
    if nc != cc:
        c = c + '/' + str(cc)
#    print >> self.stream, c.rjust(9),
#    print >> self.stream, f8(tt),
    x +=  c.rjust(9) + " "
    x +=  pstats.f8(tt) + " "
    if nc == 0:
        #print >> self.stream, ' '*8,
       x +=  ' '*8 
    else:
        #print >> self.stream, f8(float(tt)/nc),
        x +=  pstats.f8(float(tt)/nc) + " "
    #print >> self.stream, f8(ct),
    x +=  pstats.f8(ct) + " "
    if cc == 0:
        #print >> self.stream, ' '*8,
        x +=  ' '*8
    else:
        #print >> self.stream, f8(float(ct)/cc),
        x +=   pstats.f8(float(ct)/cc) + " "
    #print >> self.stream, func_std_string(func)
    x +=  pstats.func_std_string(func) + " "
    return x

def xget_print_list(self, sel_list):
    width = self.max_name_len
    if self.fcn_list:
        stat_list = self.fcn_list[:]
        msg = "   Ordered by: " + self.sort_type + '\n'
    else:
        stat_list = self.stats.keys()
        msg = "   Random listing order was used\n"

    for selection in sel_list:
        stat_list, msg = self.eval_print_amount(selection, stat_list, msg)

    count = len(stat_list)

    if not stat_list:
        return 0, stat_list
    #print >> self.stream, msg
    if count < len(self.stats):
        width = 0
        for func in stat_list:
            if  len(pstats.func_std_string(func)) > width:
                width = len(pstats.func_std_string(func))
    #return width+2, stat_list
    return msg, width+2, stat_list
```

Answer (score 50):

Stats takes an optional 'stream' argument. Simply open a file and pass the open file object to the Stats constructor as shown below. From that point any call to print_stats() will output to the stream you passed into the constructor. Hope this helps. :)

```
with open('path/to/output', 'w') as stream:
    stats = pstats.Stats('path/to/input', stream=stream)
    stats.print_stats()
```

Comment: Follow code works for me: import StringIO;stream = StringIO.StringIO(); stats = pstats.Stats(fname, stream=stream);  stats.print_stats(); stream.seek(0); print stream.read()

Answer (score 3):

How about output redirection?

```
import sys
import pstats
sys.stdout = open('readable.profile', 'w')
p = pstats.Stats('input.profile')
p.print_stats()
```

Comment: Unfortunately `p.print_stats()` does not use `sys.stdout` for printing.  If you try this you get an empty file and the info printed to console instead of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library: pstats_print2list
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pstats_print2list

`pip install pstats_print2list`
And usage:

```
from pstats_print2list import get_pstats_print2list, print_pstats_list
fname_stats = 'my_profiling_out.stats'
pstats_list = get_pstats_print2list(
    os.path.expanduser(fname_stats),
    filter_fnames=['myfile1.py', 'myfile2.py', 'root_path1'],
    exclude_fnames=['dontshow.py', 'path_dont_show'],
    sort='cumulative',
    limit=5,
)
print_pstats_list(pstats_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for another solution, where we can put the string data to a txt file. The code below will use two functions to add two numbers and then make the Profile data and finally writes it to an out.txt file.

#### main.py

```py
import cProfile
import time
import pstats
from io import StringIO

def add_slow(a, b):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return a+b

def add_fast(a, b):
    return a+b

prof = cProfile.Profile()

def main_func():
    arr = []
    prof.enable()
    for i in range(10):
        if i%2==0:
            arr.append(add_slow(i,i))
        else:
            arr.append(add_fast(i,i))
    prof.disable()
    #prof.print_stats(sort='time')
    prof.dump_stats("main_funcs.prof")
    return arr

main_func()
stream = StringIO();
stats = pstats.Stats("main_funcs.prof", stream=stream); 
stats.print_stats()
stream.seek(0)
print(16*'=',"RESULTS",16*'=')
data = stream.read()
print(data)
myText = open('out.txt', 'w')
myText.write(data)
myText.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

> [`stats.dump_stats(path/to/file)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.dump_stats)

Comment: I tried it and that file isn't readable. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: You could always just [redirect stdout to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr).