# I want Python argparse to throw an exception rather than usage

Tags: python, argparse

I don't think this is possible, but I want to handle exceptions from argparse myself.

For example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo help', required=True)
try:
    args = parser.parse_args()
except:
    do_something()
```

When I run it:

```
$ myapp.py
usage: myapp --foo foo
myapp: error: argument --foo is required
```

But I want it to fall into the exception instead.

Comment: You're not using argparse for what it was designed for, then. What are you wanting to do?

Comment: It's not a bad thing to change the way an otherwise great library works, just to tune it to a particular project.

Comment: Actually you can already do that. simply catch `SystemExit` and replace `sys.stderr` with some other object.

Comment: @jdborg: it's not *necessarily* bad, but it often is bad. In this case, I'd like to hear what you're trying to achieve—there may well be a better approach.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, it may be better to modify the argument itself. Is the argument to `--foo` optional? Can you define a custom action to handle it? These may be cleaner actions than overriding `argparse`'s decision to exit.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, If this user wants a server to have a continuous command line that runs on a server (e.g; a Flask server) and he doesn't want the app to stop running after getting an error, how would you do it?

Comment: @YoniMelki: that’s a completely different question, with *nothing* in common with this question. Search further, or ask a new question if you haven’t found anything you think matches. Comments are not a suitable place for such matters.

Comment: Python 3.9 added a `exit_on_error` parameter to `ArgumentParser()`, but it does not (yet?) throw an error for a missing required option nor an unrecognized option.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue41255.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can subclass `ArgumentParser` and override the `error` method to do something different when an error occurs:

```
class ArgumentParserError(Exception): pass

class ThrowingArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        raise ArgumentParserError(message)

parser = ThrowingArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(...)
...
```

Comment: Thought it would be something like that.  Thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something like this, though I'm glad it's an option. You see, I'm trying to print out the help menu when I get an "error: too few arguments" notification; my argparse setup requires at least one argument to run successfully, but I figure it'd be polite to print out what those commands are without the user having to run the script with the "-h" parameter. Something like:

    `parser.set_error('too few arguments', method_to_deal_with_error)`

I suppose I can always file a bug if I want this feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

in my case, argparse prints 'too few arguments' then quit. after reading the argparse code, I found it simply calls sys.exit() after printing some message. as sys.exit() does nothing but throws a SystemExit exception, you can just capture this exception.

so try this to see if it works for you.

```
    try:
        args = parser.parse_args(args)
    except SystemExit:
        .... your handler here ...
        return
```

Comment: Yes, this option is mentioned above in Bakuriu's comment.  The unittesting `test_argparse.py` file uses this approach, along with redefining `error` to create a `ErrorRaisingArgumentParser` class.

Comment: the error message is thrown out on stderr. Is there a way to catch it?

Comment: @Raj You can temporarily redirect stderr to another stream/file object, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796752/2128769