# How to catch the value that cause argparse to raise an error in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

Is it possible to catch an error raised when a value's type is wrong with argparse (invalid value but the argument is recognised) in order to see what caused the error and eventually **ignore** it (continue with the parsing)?

I know that I can override the error method of the ArgumentParser, but it gives only the error message as a string, and I would want to avoid parsing this string.

This is in order to handle some magic keywords in the CLI whatever the type defined with argparse.

Note that I read the following related question:

[Handle invalid arguments with argparse in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340252/handle-invalid-arguments-with-argparse-in-python)

and Python documentation, neither one seems to give an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an error catching `type` function.  For example wrap `int` as:

```
def trytype(astr, fn=int):
    try:
       ret = fn(astr)
    except ValueError:   
       ret = ('error', astr)
    return ret

In [51]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [52]: parser.add_argument('-f', type=trytype);
In [53]: parser.parse_args('-f 123'.split())
Out[53]: Namespace(f=123)
In [54]: parser.parse_args('-f abc'.split())
Out[54]: Namespace(f=('error', 'abc'))
```

This could be generalized to handle other type functions (may be a trytype factory function).  Also make it catch all the error types (ValueError, TypeError, ArgumentTypeError).  And customize the return value.  Here I just returned a tuple with an 'error' string and the original string.

```
In [55]: from functools import partial
In [56]: partial(trytype, fn=float)
Out[56]: functools.partial(<function trytype at 0xac13a8e4>, fn=<class 'float'>)
In [57]: partial(trytype, fn=float)('12.34')
Out[57]: 12.34
In [58]: partial(trytype, fn=int)('12.34')
Out[58]: ('error', '12.34')
In [59]: partial(trytype, fn=str)('abc')
Out[59]: 'abc'
```

accept int in one argument and float in another:

```
In [60]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [61]: parser.add_argument('-i', type=partial(trytype, fn=int));
In [62]: parser.add_argument('-f', type=partial(trytype, fn=float));
In [63]: parser.parse_args('-f abc -i123'.split())
Out[63]: Namespace(f=('error', 'abc'), i=123)
In [64]: parser.parse_args('-f 12.32 -ia23'.split())
Out[64]: Namespace(f=12.32, i=('error', 'a23'))
In [65]: parser.parse_args('-f 12e32 -ia23'.split())
Out[65]: Namespace(f=1.2e+33, i=('error', 'a23'))
In [66]: parser.parse_args('-f x2e32 -ia23'.split())
Out[66]: Namespace(f=('error', 'x2e32'), i=('error', 'a23'))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice way !

Comment: Newer versions have a parameter to raise an error instead of exitting.  It doesn't handle all errors, but should be ok for one's raised by `type`.  But you are still dependent on what the `type` function raises - valueerror, typeerror, argumenttypeerror.