# In python, can I redirect the output of print function to stderr?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stderr

There're lots of `print` function (`python 2.7`) in my program. Is there any way I can add a few lines then all the output can be redirected to `stderr`? What I want is python codes but not linux pipeline.

For example, my program is like:

```
print 'hello world'
```

I would like to add some codes like:

```
redirect_output_to_stderr()
print 'hello world'
```

Then all the output can be redirected to `stderr`.

I know `print >> sys.stderr, 'hello world'` can achieve my goal, but is it any way that can prevent from modifying the existed codes?

Comment: The _only_ way to do that _without modifying the code_ is to use a shell's redirection commands.

Comment: Oh, I guess what I need is preventing from modified the existed `print` functions. Thank you for mentioned that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this in your method:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

Comment: Or maybe don't, god this is horrible advice.

Comment: @ruohola Yeah, not a great thing to do in any code, even 6 years ago! But I guess this is exactly what the question was asking for ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 20):

In python 2.7 you can do:

```
import sys

print >> sys.stderr, "To stderr."
```

Or you can import the behavior from 3.x:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print('To stderr.', file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefinition of `print` is feature of Python 3+. However, you can change `sys.stdout` to `std.stderr`.

See: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/python-temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr)

Comment: You *can* redefine `print` in 2.7 if you do `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @lvc Didn't know that. Still change of `stdout` is shorter than function redefinition.