# redirect API Stderr python

Tags: python, stderr

I am using a python package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mygene
to do some gene id mapping. I have code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# ID mapping using mygene
# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mygene
# http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/newgene/6771106
# http://mygene-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
# 08/30/14

__author__ = 'tommy'

import mygene
import fileinput
import sys


mg = mygene.MyGeneInfo()

# mapping gene symbols to Entrez gene ids and Ensemble gene ids.
# fileinput will loop through all the lines in the input specified as file names given in command-line arguments,
# or the standard input if no arguments are provided.

# build a list from an input file with one gene name in each line
def get_gene_symbols():
    gene_symbols = []
    for line in fileinput.input():
        gene_symbol = line.strip()  # assume each line contains only one gene symbol
        gene_symbols.append(gene_symbol)
    fileinput.close()
    return gene_symbols


Entrez_ids = mg.querymany(get_gene_symbols(), scopes='symbol', fields='entrezgene', species='human', as_dataframe=True)


# set as_dataframe to True will return a pandas dataframe object

Entrez_ids.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep="\t")  # write the dataframe to stdout

# sys.stdout.write()  expects the character buffer object

Entrez_ids.to_csv("Entrez_ids.txt", sep="\t")    # write the pandas dataframe to csv
```

My question is that if I use Entrez_ids.to_csv("Entrez_ids.txt", sep="\t"), the result file will not include the stderr like ' finished...), but Entrez_ids.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep="\t") will print out both the stderr message and also the dataframe.

How can I redirect the stderr if I use  Entrez_ids.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep="\t") ?
Thank you!

Comment: On commandline, you can use `python your-file.py 2>error.log.txt` to redirect the output. Do you want something else?

Comment: Thanks, I know this trick. what I did: python my-file.py input.txt 2> /dev/null   but the stderr is still printed out in the screen. the input file is like this: CCDC83 
    MAST3 
    FLOT1 
    RPL11 
    ZDHHC20 
    LUC7L3 
    SNORD49A  
    CTSH 
    ACOT8  with one gene name per line. you can test it out by yourself. I think it is because the mg.querymany function will return both the error message and the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you:

[In python, can I redirect the output of print function to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860372/in-python-can-i-redirect-the-output-of-print-function-to-stderr?rq=1)

```
import sys
sys.stderr = to_your_file_object
```

You can use `devnull` to suppress the output:

```
import os
f = open(os.devnull,"w")
sys.stderr = f
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Entrez_ids.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep="\t") will write both the error message and dataframe returned by the mg.querymany function to the screen.

Comment: Does it mean that error is written on stdout? Try redirecting stdout only.

Comment: could you please show me how exactly to do this (with code) ? Thank you. I saw this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956142/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-python  but it seems a little bit too advanced for me.

Comment: You can use `sys.stdout = f` to redirect `stdout` before calling your function. If nothing prints on the console, it means that error is being printed on `stdout`.