# Logging process output to file in real time

Tags: linux, bash

I have a python script running on startup in the background.  Its print commands do not come through to the bash console as they do when calling the script manually with e.g. `python script.py`.  Output and errors can be redirected to file by calling `python script.py > log.txt 2>&1`.  But after startup, as the script runs, I can see the log file but it has zero size, so is presumably waiting for the script to end.  Calling it with `cat` returns nothing.  I've tried using append >> instead with no luck.

Is there any way to make the output happen in real time, so it can be viewed?

Comment: Be sure to [flush the output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/478288) to make sure buffering isn't the culprit.

Comment: Use stderr to log - it's not buffered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860372/in-python-can-i-redirect-the-output-of-print-function-to-stderr

Comment: @chrisaycock is right that inserting `sys.stdout.flush()` into the code fixes it.  Any strong views on which method is optimal?

Comment: They're basically the same. It just calls `flush()` internally for you in the stderr case.

Comment: @chrisaycock welcome to submit as answer, or I can if you prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is being buffered, so [flush](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/478288) it inside the Python script to ensure the results will appear:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```