# Pandas Bad Lines Warning Capture

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Is there any way in Pandas to capture the warning produced by setting error_bad_lines = False and warn_bad_lines = True? For instance the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
data = StringIO("""a,b,c
                   1,2,3
                   4,5,6
                   6,7,8,9
                   1,2,5
                   3,4,5""")
pd.read_csv(data, warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)
```

produces the warning:

```
Skipping line 4: expected 3 fields, saw 4
```

I'd like to store this output to  a string so that I can eventually write it to a log file to keep track of records that are being skipped.

I tried using the **warning** module but it doesn't appear as though this "warning" is of the traditional sense. I'm using Python 2.7 and Pandas 0.16.

Comment: It is possible to print the bad line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it isn't implemented to pandas.
[source1](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2842), [source2](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5686)

My solutions:

**1. Pre or after processing**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv      

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)

#compare length of rows by recommended value:
RECOMMENDED = 3

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if (len(row) != RECOMMENDED):
            print ("Length of row is: %r" % len(row) )
            print row

#compare length of rows by length of columns in df
lencols = len(df.columns)
print lencols

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if (len(row) != lencols):
            print ("Length of row is: %r" % len(row) )
            print row
```

**2. Replaces sys.stdout**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

class RedirectStdStreams(object):
    def __init__(self, stdout=None, stderr=None):
        self._stdout = stdout or sys.stdout
        self._stderr = stderr or sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stdout, self.old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
        self.old_stdout.flush(); self.old_stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = self._stdout, self._stderr

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._stdout.flush(); self._stderr.flush()
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        sys.stderr = self.old_stderr


if __name__ == '__main__':

    devnull = open('log.txt', 'w')

    #replaces sys.stdout, sys.stderr, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6796752/2901002
    with RedirectStdStreams(stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull):
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will probably go with the second solution since I need to iterate over several files and unfortunately we're stuck with this format.

Answer (score 6):

I can't help you with older than Python 3, but I've had very good success with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import io

# Redirect stderr to something we can report on.
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stderr(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(
        new_file_name, header=None, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, dtype=header_types
    )
if f.getvalue():
    logger.warning("Had parsing errors: {}".format(f.getvalue()))
```

I searched for this issue a number of times and kept being pointed to this questions. Hope it helps someone else, later on.

Comment: can you define `logger`?

Comment: posted an edit. @scottlittle, replace `logger.warning` with `print`