# How to count the number of fields in each row of a broken csv

Tags: python

I have a number of supposed csv's but in fact they have some rows with different numbers of fields. I would like to found out which rows these are and look at them.  If the csv's weren't broken I would just use pandas and do:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

But this isn't suitable for data cleaning and preprocessing I need to do.

How can I find the number of fields in each row in a "csv" file?  Is it, for example, possible to just read in one row at a time, without remembering the number of fields from previous rows?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You can visually get a list of all "bad" lines by calling `pd.read_csv('file.csv',error_bad_lines=False)`. I am not sure you can store it in a variable for further processing.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334966/pandas-bad-lines-warning-capture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV is not a fully defined standard, so close to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) you can do something like this

```
import re
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    print([re.sub(r'("[^"]*),([^"]*")', r'\1<comma>\2', l).count(',') for l in f.readlines()])
```

which counts the *commas* after replacing the ones enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following works.

```
import csv
def f(s):
    return map(len,csv.reader(s.split("\n"))
```