# How can we store the warning message generated when executing a pandas read_csv() to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, warnings

I am using pandas to read a file using `read_csv()`. In it I have set warn_bad_lines as `True` and error_bad_lines as `False` to identify rows with extra delimiters. And I am getting proper warnings. Can I store these warnings into a variable so that i can use it later?

This is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter = '|', error_bad_lines = False , warn_bad_lines = True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, check this question, i guess it's the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334966/pandas-bad-lines-warning-capture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Bad Lines Warning Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334966/pandas-bad-lines-warning-capture)

Comment: The duplicate addresses the identical question. It even focuses on `read_csv()`