# Pandas skipping lines when in read_csv, can I record these to variable/log file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've seen similar questions on here but nothing that is quite what I want to do.

I'm reading in a tsv/csv file using

```
        try:
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(
                filepath_or_buffer=filename_or_obj,
                sep='\t',
                encoding='utf-8',
                skip_blank_lines=True,
                error_bad_lines=False,
                warn_bad_lines=True,
                dtype=data_type_dict,
                engine='python',
                quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
            )
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(
                filepath_or_buffer=exception_filename_or_obj,
                sep='\t',
                encoding='latin-1',
                skip_blank_lines=True,
                error_bad_lines=False,
                warn_bad_lines=True,
                dtype=data_type_dict,
                engine='python',
                quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
            )
```

I have clearly defined headers within the file but sometimes I see that the file has unexpected additional columns and get the following messages in the console

`Skipping line 251643: Expected 20 fields in line 251643, saw 21`

This is fine for my process, I would just like to know a way that I can record these messages or lines to either a dataframe or log file so that I know what lines have been skipped. Due to the fact that the files can be submitted by anyone and it's an issue with formatting, I'm not interested in fixing the message, just recording out the line numbers that fail

Massive thanks in advance :)

Edit: include try except clause

Comment: use `try - except` to record the messages, inside loop

Comment: @anurag there's no exception raised

Comment: @C.Nivs can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @anurag, it happens for any data where the amount of columns in the row exceeds the amount of columns in the header row (example below)

    `COL_1, COL_2, COL_3
    data1, data2, data3
    data1, data2, data3, data4 <-this line will cause the error`

As C.Nivs says, this is displays in console despite not being in an exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334966/pandas-bad-lines-warning-capture

Comment: @C.Nivs `there's no exception raised` - that is because you are using the option `error_bad_lines=False`. It is actually a good move. Redirect the error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce the issue, I used the following CSV file (*dummy.csv*):

```bash
F1,F2,F3
11,A,10.54
18,B,0.12,low
24,A,19.00
10,C,7.01,low
22,D,39.11,high
49,E,12.12
```

It may be noted that some lines have extra fields.

Since, we are using `error_bad_lines=False`, no errors/exceptions will be raised, so `try-except` is not the way ahead. We need to redirect the `stderr`:

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import pandas as pd
# import io

with open('error_messages.log', 'w') as h:
    # f = io.StringIO()
    # with redirect_stderr(f):
    with redirect_stderr(h):
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='dummy.csv',
                sep=',',            # change it for your data
                encoding='latin-1',
                skip_blank_lines=True,
                error_bad_lines=False,
                # dtype=data_type_dict,
                engine='python',
                # quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
                )
        # h.write(f.getvalue())      # Write the error messages to log file

print(df)
```

The above code will write the messages to a log file!

Here is a sample output from the log file:

```bash
Skipping line 3: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
Skipping line 5: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 4
Skipping line 6: Expected 3 fields in line 6, saw 4
```

**Update**

Modified the code based on a suggestion (in comments below)

Comment: I commented out `dtype` and `quoting`, enable them for your use!

Comment: This is a nice answer. I tried it without using `io.StringIO` instance. Pass `h` to `redirect_stderr` and remove `h.write(f.getvalue())`.

Comment: @anurag, perfect that's worked, big thank you :)