# Redirecting external function stdout to log file as they happen

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Using python 2.7
I am calling an external library function and I want to print all the logs/prints that this function generates to a file. I would like to update the file with the logs as they happen.
I am using ipython notebook so if there is an easier way which is notebook specific I will be ok with that too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to perform the redirection in your shell, not from within the python code.

From a typical Unix command line, you can use the `tee` command:

```
python program.py | tee logfile
```