# sys.stdout as default function argument

Tags: python, stdout, default-value, sys

Suppose we have the following dummy function:

```
import sys

def writeline(text, stream=sys.stdout):
    stream.write(text + '\n')

with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    # writes to /path/to/file
    writeline('foo', f)

# writes to standard output
writeline('bar')
```

Given that Python evaluates default arguments for functions at definition time, is setting `sys.stdout` as default argument safe, or may it have unintended side effects?

Comment: Unless you'll [temporarily redirect `stdout` within your client code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr), you should be fine. If you want to do this redirection, function would still hold a reference to original stdout, therefore redirection will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem I think of, is that you sometimes **want to redirect `sys.stdout` to a file (or pipe, device, etc.)** yourself.

For instance your main program could look like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        sys.stdout = open(sys.argv[1],'w')
    try:
        # ... run the program
    finally:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            sys.stdout.close()
```

This could be useful if you want your program to *log to a file* if you mention one (like `python3 file.py logfile.log`). Now since you set the `sys.stdout`, that modification will not be noted by your `writeline` method.

Therefore I think it is more safe to write:

```
def writeline(text, stream = None):
    if stream is None:
        stream = sys.stdout
    stream.write(text + '\n')
```

In general it is probably good advice to set *immutable* objects as default parameters (like `None`, `False`, `(1,)`, etc.). Only in rare circumstances immutable ones (or ones that might change reference) are used on purpose in Python.

If you are however sure that you will not redirect `sys.stdout` to a file, pipe, etc. It is safe.

Comment: Good point. I am aware of the reason it is better to set _immutable_ objects as default parameters, but I thought it wasn't necessary in this case because I didn't consider the possibility that `sys.stdout` itself is allowed to change.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom most frequently used when there are doubts about the *constant* value of a named argument is to set the argument to `None`, so the resolution is always done at runtime against the values that are current at invocation time:

```
def writeline(text, stream=None):
    if stream is None:
        stream = sys.stdout
    stream.write(text + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3's print function, if the `file` argument is `None` output will be printed to `stdout` as usual. So you can just make the default value `None` like so:

```
def write_something(items, outfile=None):
    for item in items:
        print(item, file=outfile)
```