# How to clear terminal output when opening URL using webbrowser in python?

Tags: python, shell, python-webbrowser

I am using `webbrowser` to open a URL using Python but the problem is after opening the URL `webbrowser` module prints unnecessary output on terminal.
[image: terminal output]

I searched on google but didn't find any useful answer.

Code used:

```py
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/")
```

I just want to get rid of browser output in terminal not the whole output.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

`python script.py >/dev/null 2>&1`

`>/dev/null` redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null`, preventing the terminal from outputting it.

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`, which is then sent to `/dev/null`, to hide errors.

Comment: Note this affects the output of the entire script.

Comment: @minseong I just want to get rid of those browsers output on control

Comment: You could also do output redirection with a context manager, as explained in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752455/1977847