# disable the keras "Found # images belonging to # classes." message

Tags: keras

Is there some way to disable this diagnostic message? It's driving me nuts. It's either in the DataGenerator class or the flow_from_directory method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As absurd as it sounds, it appears that: no, there is no way.

It is an [unconditional print](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ce5728bbd36004c7a17b86e69a8e59b21d6ee6d4/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py#L104) (no logging, just a raw dog print).

By the way, there is an (apparently ignored / forgotten) [open issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14030) on GitHub.

But, we can use the [contextlib workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747258/1642116).