# Modifying existing logger configuration of a python package

Tags: python, logging, optimization, cvxpy, cvxopt

I am currently using `cvxpy` for my project. When I solve an optimization problem, I have the option to turn the verbose flag on using `prob.solve(solver=cvx.CVXOPT, verbose=True)`. When I do that, the logger starts printing the DEBUG level log messages to the console.

I understand that it is because of the following section in [`cvxpy` source code](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/blob/master/cvxpy/settings.py).

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger("__cvxpy__")
LOGGER.propagate = False
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt="(CVXPY) %(asctime)s: %(message)s", datefmt="%b %d %I:%M:%S %p"
)
_stream_handler.setFormatter(_formatter)
LOGGER.addHandler(_stream_handler)
```

How do I redirect the messages to a file without hacking the original source code? Can there be a setter method? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvxpy doesn't supply any direct option to print log to a file, but rather it uses `sys.stdout`.

You can, however, redirect `sys.stdout` into a file instead of the console. To do that see: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python/) or [Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr) for example.

You redirect output into a file in your program right before the `.solve()` call, and it should print the log into a file. The easiest way is with [contextlib.redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)

That way when you call to `solve` with `verbose=True`, the `sys.stdout` that mentioned in the block of code you mentioned will redirect to a file instead of the console. If you're not familiar with stdin, stdout and stderr I would recommend to have a quick read about them first.