# ffmpeg_extract_subclip function and moviepy string output error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube, moviepy, pytube

I have been developing this small application to download and cut Youtube videos. **It works fine** but an error or misformatted message is the issue I have not fixed. When it comes to the cutting process, the function `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` is used and right after that point, I get the weird error below:
[image]

Below, the script working fine.
[image]

The function responsible for cutting the video

```py
# cutting the video by section
def cut_video(video_local_path, start_time, end_time, final_file):

    print("- Cutting your video...")
    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(video_local_path, time_to_sec(start_time), time_to_sec(end_time), targetname=f"{final_file}.mp4")
```

If necessary, you can check the full code [here](https://github.com/joaov777/ytd-cli) on github.

I have extensively read the API for ffmpeg and moviepy, debugged on vscode and checked alternatives like VideoFileClip but it would never give me the same performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just calling FFmpeg yourself? Using subprocess, it should be as simple as `sp.run([ffmpeg_path, '-ss', start_time, '-to', end_time, '-i', video_local_path, final_file], stderr=sp.NULL, stdout=sp.NULL)`.

Comment: If I do the way you are saying, will I be relying on the ffmpeg installed by the system or it really makes no difference between doing this through Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to work around this behavior.

**1. Momentarily redirect stdout/stderr**

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr)

**2. Use FFmpeg directly**

[`moviepy`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/8eaf3f02c5cf812e89f03e925cb2fa5e05b8d29a/setup.py#L75) appears to be depending on [`imageio-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/imageio/imageio-ffmpeg) for its FFmpeg support, and `imageio-ffmpeg` gets the FFmpeg path from `IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE` environmental path <strike>downloads FFmpeg executables when the package is installed</strike>. So, you should be able to do the following

```py
import imageio_ffmpeg
import subprocess as sp

ffmpeg_path = imageio_ffmpeg.get_ffmpeg_exe()

sp.run([ffmpeg_path, '-ss', start_time, '-to', end_time, '-i', video_local_path, 
       final_file, '-y'], stderr=sp.NULL, stdout=sp.NULL)
```

Now, if you are using `moviepy` only for this operation (and other FFmpeg operations), you can drop it altogether and set `ffmpeg_path` to the FFmpeg path. <strike>and just download the FFmpeg binaries via [`ffmpeg-downloader`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpeg-downloader) or [`static-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/zackees/static_ffmpeg) package. The former is a better choice if you use FFmpeg in multiple venvs (as it saves FFmpeg files in an OS designated user data area, so it only downloads once). The latter is 100% automatic downloading approach similar to `imageio-ffmpeg` but with no frills</strike>.

[edit: `imageio-ffmpeg` does not download FFmpeg on its own, so you should already have the FFmpeg executables on your system.]

Comment: Your response actually solved it for me. The only adjustment I made was to change the ffmpeg command a bit since I still got errors regarding the NULL attribute for stderr and stdout. In any case, the final command is below and it works perfectly:

```ffmpeg_path = imageio_ffmpeg.get_ffmpeg_exe()
    sp.call([ffmpeg_path, '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-ss', start_time, '-to', end_time, '-i', video_local_path, '-c', 'copy', f"{final_file}.mp4"])
``` 
Thank you!