# How to Suppress Qhull Message using scipy.spacial ConvexHull

Tags: scipy, message, suppress, qhull

Using `ConvexHull(coordinates, qhull_options="QJ")` every once in a while I get a large number of the message `Killing degenerate triangle` in `stdout`. There are no errors or suspicious results. So it looks like qhull successfully removed some degenerate triangles. As the message tends to clutter up my output I would like to mute it.

I already looked at different `qhull_options` but no success. I even googled that message with - in a verbal sense - no results. So I have no idea where it comes from beside the call to `ConvexHull`. Trying to catch the message as python warning was also not successful. It is also no `QhullError`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may have some success with redirecting [stdout or stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49747258/2912349).

Comment: CORRECTION: Thanks Paul for your hint. I did try redirecting stdout but overlooked the possibility it was cached so I tried  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/21960560 but it still doesn't work for me. 

It anyway is a little sad, one can not control the messages in another way. This does seem like a workaround.