# Errno 10048 when trying to read again from network through Bacpypes

Tags: python, sockets, errno, bacnet

I use a python library called Bacpypes in order to read bacnet points in network. In my first trial of reading my points with function MultipleReadProperty , there is no problem. I get all values without any problem. But in second poll i get an error about socket like following :

```
[0.0, 1149064.0, 1941115.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 13525024.0, 448152.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[31/Jan/2015:11:39:33] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpdispatch.py", line 61, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sansal\Desktop\Projeler\sayac_okuma8\main2.py", line 231, in sayac_oku
    readings_from_counters=ReadCounters(counters_list)
  File "C:\Users\Sansal\Desktop\Projeler\sayac_okuma8\main2.py", line 153, in ReadCounters
    this_application = ReadPointListApplication(points_list, this_device, args.ini.address)
  File "C:\Users\Sansal\Desktop\Projeler\sayac_okuma8\main2.py", line 43, in __init__
    BIPSimpleApplication.__init__(self, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bacpypes-0.10.6-py2.7.egg\bacpypes\app.py", line 555, in __init__
    self.mux = UDPMultiplexer(self.localAddress)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bacpypes-0.10.6-py2.7.egg\bacpypes\bvllservice.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.directPort = udp.UDPDirector(self.addrTuple)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bacpypes-0.10.6-py2.7.egg\bacpypes\udp.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.bind(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 342, in bind
    return self.socket.bind(addr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

As seen at first line, i get all values from network with no problem.

To solve problem, i used stop() function of Bacpypes library in a few points of code. Especially just before the code that starts polling. But, it appears that i cant somehow close the socket. Could you please make some suggestions about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362542/python-server-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-is-normally-permitted)

Comment: Ok i did that. But now i get errorno 10035.

Comment: can you update the question with the new error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacpypes has recently been update to version 0.15 and a lot of effort has been made in the documentation. There a re a lot of new features and the code has been simplified for typical things like whois, IAm.

I suggest you have a look http://bacpypes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

and here : https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes/blob/master/samples/MultipleReadProperty.py

I can also suggest BAC0 (http://bac0.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is built on the top of bacpypes and provide out-of-the box features to communicate with BACnet devices. (Disclaimer : BAC0 is my project and I'm contributor to bacpypes)