# python Bluetooth - How to use Socket address more than once on windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, bluetooth

this same question has been asked several times, and most answers where related to `TCP/IP`. But im looking for `Bluetooth` related.

Im trying to send information between 2 machines through bluetooth. I installed `pybluez` on both linux and windows, It worked fine on discovering other nearby devices on both Os. Later i used [this code](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html) as an example to send information. It worked fine when, client was linux machine and server was linux machine. When i run the server side code on windows7 i got the error

```
server_sock.bind(("",port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 60, in bind
    status = bt.bind (self._sockfd, addr, port)
IOError: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

which i realized that on windows once the port is used, just closing the address/port is not sufficient but also has to be set to reuse([from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12362623/3869739)).
But there is no similar library inside `bluetooth.BluetoothSocket` to reuse the address/port.

How can i use a socket more than once? or is there an alternative way,..?

**Code:**

```
import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Comment: Can u post your piece of code related to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem as you but resolved it yesterday and thought maybe you could try the same approach as me. Try using a different port number instead of port 1. I personally used port 5 (instea of 1) and stopped having this issue. Hope it helps! For some reason I am not quite sure about yet, port 1 cannot be re-used after a first successful connection in that port.

Answer (score 0):

reset hciconfig, this is happening because the socket is already in use