# Sending Data Over Bluetooth Continuously

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, raspbian

I am trying to send data over a Bluetooth continuously from my computer to a raspberry pi. It works when i send the data once, and after that it throws a connection reset by peer error. I am new to python and bluetooth language please help.

#### Client Code

```
import Bluetooth
def connect(addr):
 serverMACAddress = addr
 port = 2
 s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
 s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
 while 1:
    text = raw_input() # Note change to the old (Python 2) raw_input
    if text == "quit":
      break
    if(addr): 
       s.send(text)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(addr)
 s.close()

addr = XXX-XXX-XXX MAC address of the server bluetooth
while(1):
  connect(addr)
```

#### Receiver Code

```
import bluetooth
def receiveMessages():
  server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
  
  port = 2
  server_sock.bind(("",port))
  server_sock.listen(1)
  
  client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
  print("Accepted connection from " + str(address))
  
  data = client_sock.recv(1024)
  print("received [%s]" % data)
  time.sleep(1)
  client_sock.close()
  server_sock.close()

while(1):
  receiveMessages()
```

Comment: Please try to improve your question. You have no `import` statements, and no code actually calling any of your functions. Presumably there is some code running at the other end of the connection too?

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32792445/2836621

Comment: Nevermind, i was able to fix it by reconnecting to the bluetooth with the given Mac address everytime i send a new message