# Python Socket Server Binding Error

Tags: python, sockets, server, runtime-error

I have a `Python Socket server` program, and for whatever reason the program can't bind the host and port together. 
Here's my code:

```
import socket
import sys

host = ""
port = 9999
s = socket.socket()

try:
    ("Binding socket to port: " + str(port))
    s.bind((host, 9999))
    s.listen(5)
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Socket binding error: " + str(msg) + "\n" + "Retrying...")

conn, address = s.accept()
print("Connection has been established: " + "IP " + address[0] + " Port " + str(address[1]))
while True:
    cmd = input()
    if cmd == "quit":
        conn.close()
        s.close()
        sys.exit()
    if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
        conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
        client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
        print(client_response, end=="")

conn.close()
```

I've had it print the error, and it says: `Socket binding error: [Errno 10048]` Only one usage of each socket address `(protocol/network address/port)` is normally permitted.

Does anyone know what this means and what I should do?

Comment: Probably an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362542/python-server-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-is-normally-permitted

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing: But did you run the code before?
Because then you might not have come to perform the `conn.close()`.
And therefore the port is still used (by your first run) when trying again.
On Linux you could find the python process by calling
`lsof -i :9999`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I figured out that I just needed to get a different port number; it is probably in use in some other program. That's a really cool suggestion about using the for loop to try to find an available port!

Answer (score 0):

That error message says the port is already in use (bound). It sounds like you've got a second copy of the program running that is already bound to port 9999. Try logging out or rebooting if you can't find another way to get rid of it.