# Python pickle error when using multiprocessing inside class method

Tags: python, windows, oop, multiprocessing, pickle

In the class `foo` in `foomodule.py` below, I am getting an error in the `run_with_multiprocessing` method. The method breaks up the number of records in `self._data` into chunks and calls  `somefunc()` using a subset of the data, for example `somefunc(data[0:800], 800)` in the first iteration, if `limit = 800`.

I have done this, because running 10 * 1k records vs. 1 * 10k records shows a great performance improvement in a variation of the `run_with_multiprocessing` function that does the same thing, just without multiprocessing. Now I want to use `multiprocessing` to see if I can improve performance even more.

I am running python 3.8.2 on Windows 8.1. I am fairly new to python and multiprocessing. Thank you so much for your help.

```
# foomodule.py
import multiprocessing

class foo:
    def __init__(self, data, record_count):
        self._data = data
        self._record_count = record_count

    def some_func(self, data, record_count):
        # looping through self._data and doing some work    


    def run_with_multiprocessing(self, limit):
        step = 0
        while step < self._record_count:
            if self._record_count - step < limit:
                proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.some_func, args=(self._data[step:self._record_count], self._record_count-step))
                proc.start()
                proc.join()
                step = self._record_count
                break

            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.some_func, args=(self._data[step:self._record_count], self._record_count-step))
            proc.start()
            proc.join()
            step += limit
        return
```

When using the class in `script.py`, I get the following error:

```
import foomodule

# data is a mysql result set with, say, 10'000 rows
start = time.time()
bar = foomodule.foo(data, 10000)
limit = 800
bar.run_with_multiprocessing(limit)
end = time.time()
print("finished after " + str(round(end-start, 2)) + "s")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/coding/python/project/script.py", line 29, in <module>
    bar.run_with_multiprocessing(limit)
  File "C:\coding\python\project\foomodule.py", line 303, in run_with_multiprocessing
    proc.start()
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 272, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object")
TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object
```

Comment: Is there some sort of connection to the database in data?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for looking into this. When the ```foo()``` object is created, several DB calls are made in different functions called from ```__init__()``` to populate attributes of the class with information. The method ```some_func()``` itself has no DB calls, but accesses those class attributes. The function does write to a log.txt file though.. does that matter? The log.txt file is opened in ```__init__()``` and closed in ```__del__()```.

Comment: Since the error states that there is a SSLSocket somewhere lurking in your data I'm guessing there is a connection to your database still alive when you call the multiprocessing method. Could you try closing all connections prior to calling `run_with_multiprocessing`?

Comment: Also are the different processes writing to the same file? If that is the case I would advise you to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 3):

## You divide and you will win

### Problem

If a **SSLSocket** object you add it as argument in `multiprocessing.Process()`, the **SSLSocket** cannot be [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

### Solution

**As you can't serialize a SSLSocket, you do it in the subprocess** (function passed as argument in `multiprocessing.Process()`)

#### Server

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ssl,multiprocessing
from sources.ClientListener import ClientListener

class SocketServer:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.args = kwargs["args"]
        self.__createSocket()

    def __handlerClients(self):
        try:
            while self.sock:
                # The sock.accept() allows create a subprocess when there is a connection established
                # IMPORTANT: I don't add SSL at socket object because else the SSLSocket object can't pickle when pass it by argument in processing.Process()
                conn,addr = self.sock.accept()
                eventChildStop = multiprocessing.Event()
                subprocess = multiprocessing.Process(target=ClientListener, name="client", args=(conn,addr,eventChildStop))
                # This thread is responsible of close the client's child process
                threading.Thread(target=ClientListener.exitSubprocess,name="closeChildProcess",args=(eventChildStop,subprocess,)).start()
                subprocess.start()
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            None

    def __createSocket(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #this allows address/port to be reused immediately instead before of the TIME_WAIT state
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362542/python-server-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-is-normally-permitted
        # #sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(("",self.PORT))
        self.sock.listen(self.CLIENTS)
        print(logFile().message(f"Good days. I am running ClassAdmin server, listenning {self.CLIENTS} clients by port {self.PORT}...",True,"INFO"))
        #self.sockSSL = self.context.wrap_socket(sock,server_side=True)
        self.__handlerClients()

if __name__=="__main__":
    SocketServer(args=sys.argv)
```

As you can look, in the `__handlerClients(self)` method. I do a while loop of socket object. For each iteration I know if there is connection established thanks to:

```
conn,addr = self.sock.accept()
```

So, I pass the `conn` variable in the `multiprocessing.Process()`, because `conn` is a socket object.
The different between `conn` and `self.sock` is what the `conn` has the raddr parameter, and `self.sock` hasn't it and the laddr is 0.0.0.0

**self.sock**

```
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 7788)>
```

**conn**

```
<socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.0.3', 7788), raddr=('192.168.0.20', 53078)>
```

**multiprocessing**

```
subprocess = multiprocessing.Process(target=ClientListener, name="client", args=(conn,addr,eventChildStop))
```

Is the same object.

Now go at ClientListener

#### ClientListener

```
class ClientListener:
    def __init__(self,conn,addr,event):
         # Get the connection's socket object and I in this connection add secure traffic encrypted with SSL thanks to object SSLSocket of socket module
         self.addr = addr
         self.conn = self.__SSLTunnel(conn)
         self.nick = ""
         self.__listenData()

    # This creates a ssl tunnel with the ClassAdmin's certificate and private key
    def __SSLTunnel(self,sock):
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        context.load_cert_chain(Environment.SSL("crt"),Environment.SSL("key"))
        return context.wrap_socket(sock,server_side=True)

    def __listenData(self,sock):
       # [...]
```

As you can look in the `__init__(self,conn,addr,event)` I get the `conn` variable of previous code. And in the `self.conn` save the same object but passed by **SSLSocket**

```
self.conn = self.__SSLTunnel(conn)
```

```
    def __SSLTunnel(self,sock):
        context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        context.load_cert_chain(Environment.SSL("crt"),Environment.SSL("key"))
        return context.wrap_socket(sock,server_side=True)
```

### Important

The **SSLSocket** is declared in `self.conn` because this can work with `send()` and `recv()` method.

```
data = self.conn.recv(1024)

self.conn.send("sig.SystemExit(-5000,'The nick exists and is connected',True)".encode("utf-8"))
```

The `self.sock` variable can't allow `accept()` method.

this throw a error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument in /etc/ClassAdmin/sources/ClientListener.py:14
```

What you have a good day.