# TCP error code 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: wcf, port, net.tcp

We are getting below error only from one client machine while all the other client machines are not throwing any errors. Why is this error only coming from one client machine and what is the fix for it.

Could not connect to net.tcp://XXXXXX:809/YYYYYY.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:00. TCP error code 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted XX.XX.XX.XXX:809. .  This message has been processed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python server "Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362542/python-server-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-is-normally-permitted) I know this answer is python, buy try setting the same flag.

Comment: How many clients do you have? This may be that the number of WCF server connections has reached the maximum.

Comment: We do have around 300 active users. Only one client machine was throwing this error, while other client machines doesn't have any error during the same time. I initiated a new client which didn't had any error during the same time.

Comment: Whether the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service has been started?