# Python: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, get, python-requests

I'm sending GET requests to a json API inside a loop, like this:

```
import requests

for var in my_range:
    url = f"http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/my_query/{var}"
        response = requests.get(url=url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            < do stuff >
```

I'm able to send ~ 236 requests / s, and my script runs for a few minutes, however I think all of my sockets are binding up before the TIME_WAIT state expires and they become available for reuse.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/my_query/{iter} (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03E4BCD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))
```

I see that I can lower the [TIME_WAIT](https://help.socketlabs.com/docs/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted)  state from 240 s to 30 s, however apparently that can cause other undesirable issues. I also see [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362542/python-server-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-is-normally-permitted) calling on **SO_REUSEADDR** from the sockets module but I couldn't find anything about using that solution in conjunction with the requests module. I tried **response.close()** after each request in the loop but the error persists.

Wondering how to modify my code to solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried using session?

Comment: No, could you say more on how to do that?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/ So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection). Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Sessions are usually easy to use.  Just wrap `with requests.Session() as s:` around your for loop, and then replace `requests.get` with `s.get`.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to James Lin and Frank Yellin for the tip!

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    for var in my_range:
        url = f"http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/my_query/{var}"
            response = s.get(url=url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                < do stuff >
```

Problem solved