# Python3/Windows: module 'os' has no attribute 'mkfifo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, mkfifo

I'm currently on Windows 10 using Python 3.6, and I've hit a snag on getting this following code to work which can be found here: https://github.com/Kautenja/gym-super-mario-bros/blob/master/gym_super_mario_bros/nes_env.py:

```
if not os.path.exists(self._pipe_in_name):
    os.mkfifo(self._pipe_in_name)
```

I'm looking at other questions,s and mkfifo is Linux. Is there an equivalent where I can open up that specific path from Windows without a headache?

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922185/python-os-mkfifo-for-windows