# Python script to switch user automatically

Tags: python, windows

I'm working on windows xp. How can i write a simple script which would automatically log me out of this account and log into another account on this computer upon execution of a trigger point I set in my application??

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you need to do on another account? If you want to run some commands on another account os.system and [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

To logoff, call `ExitWindowsEx()` with `EWX_LOGOFF` (0). To automatically login afterwards, write `DefaultUserName` and `DefaultPassword` to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`. You may also need to set `AutoAdminLogon` to 1. Don't forget to later remove the registry keys or it'll just keep logging into that user forever.

In python, you can use ctypes to call the function and _winreg to write to the registry.

```
# setup login
from _winreg import *
key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon', 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
SetValueEx(key, "DefaultUserName", 0, REG_SZ, "username")
SetValueEx(key, "DefaultPassword", 0, REG_SZ, "password")
SetValueEx(key, "AutoAdminLogon", 0, REG_DWORD, 1)
CloseKey(key)
# logoff
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ExitWindowsEx(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and suggest there probably isn't any Python library that can do this directly. Instead, you will need to call some C win32 functions from Python.

I think your best bet is to split this up into two separate questions.

The first question is "How do I programmatically, in Win32, initiate a log-out and log in as a different user?"

That will hopefully be answered by some Windows expert, even if they are unfamiliar with Python.

I don't know much about this, but it sounds awfully ambitious. Triggering a log-out might be possible, but triggering a log-in as a different user (presumably stopping to ask the user for a password)

The second question is "How do I call these win32 functions from within Python?"

That is a fairly regular request and there should be the expertise on StackOverflow to help.

Comment: The second question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-apis-with-python