# Getting Physical Screen Size in Python

Tags: python, gtk, screen

I have made a working program in which I use a pygame window. I have a picture background in the pygame window. The program registers the position where the mouse is clicked and when it is released. It outputs the distance in pixels. I want the program to output the distance in inches. Is there any way to get the physical and pixel size of any screen or monitor? Near universality within windows is a requirement of my program.

```
import pygame, sys, math

LEFT = 1
pos1x = 0
pos2x = 0
pos1y = 0
pos2y = 0

running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1000))

back_image = pygame.image.load("Monte_Alban.jpg")
screen.blit(back_image, [0,0])
while running:

 pygame.display.flip()
 event = pygame.event.poll()
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
     running = False
     pygame.quit()

 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
     pos1x,pos1y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == LEFT:
     pos2x,pos2y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     distx = abs(pos2x-pos1x)
     disty = abs(pos2y-pos1y)
     print ("Horizontal distane equals: %d" % distx)
     print ("Vertical distance equals: %d" % disty)
```

Comment: I forgot to paste in LEFT = 1 at top of code

Comment: You should [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789) your question body to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the resolution (width and height of the monitor) like so:

```
info = pygame.display.Info()
width = info.current_w
height = info.current_h
```

As for the physical size, it is impossible to get. You could however deduce it from the monitor's pixel density. However that information is also unattainable, *unless* you are willing to work with the win32 API, specifically the [GetDpiForMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280510(v=vs.85).aspx) function. There are plenty of resources out there on how to utilize win32 functions in python. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1025029/7662085) thread should get you started.